# How to update Tic Tac Toe board without printing multiple boards?

Tags: c++

I´ve been trying to make Tic Tac Toe in C++ and I can´t seem to figure out how to update the board without printing it all over again in a new line (every time a player makes a move a new board is printed below the previous one). The only solution I´ve found is using system("cls"), but this doesn´t seem like an optimal solution since the program offers initial instructions for the user that I find reduntant to reprint every time a player makes a move (I don't want to clear the entire screen). I've also read that '\r' can be used to print over a line that has  already been used, but I don't know how to apply this to my program.

```
    // This is the Tic Tac Toe board (this is declared in main())
    std::string board[5][5] = {
        { "   ", "|", "   ", "|", "   " },
        { "---", "-", "---", "-", "---" },
        { "   ", "|", "   ", "|", "   " },
        { "---", "-", "---", "-", "---" },
        { "   ", "|", "   ", "|", "   " },
    };

    // Update the board (this is part of a function which reads user input and changes 'board' accordingly.) 
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Tic Tac Toe v1.0\n";
    std::cout << "Hi, This is my first C++ game!\nPress the corresponding key to mark a field in the board. X Begins.\n\n";
    std::cout << " q | w | e\n ----------\n a | s | d\n ----------\n z | x | c\n\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            std::cout << board[x][y];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

The 'board' 2D array holds the iconic number sign shape of the Tic Tac Toe's board, wihle the for loop updates the board (clearing the entire screen to avoid printing multiple boards).

Comment: I'm guessing this will be OS-dependent. What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows, obviously, since he mentioned `cls`.

Comment: Look into [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).  Btw; what's wrong with clearing the screen and then drawing everything again? That's what you'd do in any graphical program (and what modern GPUs are optimized for)..

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your OS.  On a Linux console, you can print an ASCII form feed character, `'\L'`, to clear the screen, followed by a new board.  The user will just see the updated board, possibly with a bit of flicker.  You could also compile with `ncurses` to get more advanced screen mode.

On Windows, [the code is a little more complicated.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You might want to wrap this OS-dependent code in a function definition, and use `#ifdef` blocks in its source file to select the right code for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using the standard i/o manipulators you can only delete only the current line you're writing, by using the `'\r'` *carriage return* character you mentioned. Just put it at the beginning of the line you want to overwrite and flush the output, like this:

```
cout << "\r" << "Your string" << std::flush
```

But as soon as you insert a new line there not much you can do to go back. A bit more complex solution but which is suited for terminal-like games is using the [Ncurses](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html) library, which provides control over the whole terminal screen.